# Are "type constructor" and "generic type" the same thing?

Tags: scala, type-systems

I'm not clear on these two words, are they the same thing?

And, for this scala code:

```
class Box[T]
```

Can I say:

1. I defined a type constructor `Box`?
2. I defined a type constructor `Box[T]`
3. I defined a generic type `Box[T]`

Comment: You can use `:kind -v class Box[T]` in Scala 2.11 REPL. You will see this: `Box's kind is F[A], * -> *, This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.`